# Configuration binding extension could not be found

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have created a simple wcf service which used the WCF Service Library template.  Everything works fine when using the default soap bindings, however when i attempt to modify the service to add a REST binding it fails with the following error:

"Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly."

I think i'm missing some very basic step here.  Can anyone help me out?

The relevant snippits from my config file are below:

```
<service name="WebService.Service1">
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" />
</service>

<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="RestBehavior">
    <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Service Pack 1 for .NET 3.5 and it seemed to fix the problem.